# Is it possible to have infinite chain of jquery object .then()?

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a wordpress site with some custom queries loaded via ajax. I'm successfully loading paged posts archive. The problem is that my paged posts archive comes with numeric pagination. I basically know how to ajaxify pagination as well. After my posts are loaded I use jquery .then() with additional callback (It does the same as first call, just passing new $paged argument). But there are planty of paginations - in this case I had to make lots of the same .then() calback, one after the another.
Like `$.post( ... ).then(function() { $post(...).then(function() { $post(...).then(function() { $post(...).then() }) }) })` ect.

Is it possible to make an infinite chain instead?

Here is my code:

```
    function returnAjax() { 

     jQuery.post(
     PT_Ajax.ajaxurl,
      {
         // wp ajax action
         action : 'ajax-inputtitleSubmit',
          // vars
          //title : $('input[name=title]').val(),
          // send the nonce along with the request
          //poste : $('.form-signin').attr("id"),
          // send the nonce along with the request
          region : region,

          nextNonce : PT_Ajax.nextNonce
             },
              function( response ) {
              jQuery('#allPlaces').html(response);
        }
        ).then(function() {
          function second() {
          jQuery('.pagination a').click(function(event) {
          jQuery('#allPlaces').html('<div class="fa-wrapp"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-4x"></i></div>');
          var paged = jQuery(this).text();
          //alert(paged);
          event.preventDefault();
           jQuery.post(
             PT_Ajax.ajaxurl,
              {
               // wp ajax action
              action : 'ajax-inputtitleSubmit',
              // vars
              //title : $('input[name=title]').val(),
              // send the nonce along with the request
              //poste : $('.form-signin').attr("id"),
              // send the nonce along with the request
              region: region,
              paged: paged,
              nextNonce : PT_Ajax.nextNonce
              },
              function( response ) {
         jQuery('#allPlaces').html(response);

         }
       );
   });
     return false;
    };
     second();  
   });
     return false;
    };
 returnAjax();
 });
```

Comment: Yes. send the first request, then use .then on the returned promise, in the callback send the next request and return the promise, and keep chaining.

Comment: Not gonna work like that and the second thing is doing so is against DRY principle

Comment: I never said anything about repeating it, you could just as well keep chaining with a recursive function or a loop.

Comment: My point is everything you need to solve this scenario already exists. jQuery's promise system is built in such a way that you can use it either with a pyramid of callbacks or a flat list of chained thens, or even an array of promises that you listen for all to complete. Whatever you need.

Comment: Thanks for your help - I'm pretty close, perhaps I just have to take a close look into documentation to understand things properly